grub2 : how to list BLSCFG menu entries on Host OS shell (bash) (not grub) command line?
On my Fedora-40 Linux x86_64 laptop box, /boot/grub2/grub.cfg is configured to use BLSCFG -
could anyone please explain more about BLSCFG , and how I might use it from bash command line
to list menu entries so that I can use grub2-reboot command, giving menu entry number ?
   ```
   [root@host:~] # cat /etc/default/grub
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
   GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
   #GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="true"
   GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=${elided} rd.lvm.lv=LNX_ROOT/FEDORA rhgb=no plymouth.use-simpledrm enforcing=0 gnome.initial-setup=no mitigations=off "
  #GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
  GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG="true"
  #GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
  GRUB_GRUBENV_UPDATE="yes"
  GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST="C08C-8F0D@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi"
  ```

The problem is, my /boot/grub2/grub.cfg thus uses DYNAMIC menu-entries , ie.
BLSCFG looks at what is in the /boot/vmlinux* on the target boot device and
then chooses the latest / last booted entry ?
Then how can I tell FC-40 to 'reboot to selected grub menu entry'  with the
grub2-reboot command ,  if I cannot list the menu entries ?
I want to ensure, if  'lernel-install add ...' has rebuilt the Rescue kernel initramfs & done UEFI
cfg updates AFTER it has rebuilt the non-rescue kernel images & done its cfg,
then the non-rescue kernel remains the default next boot kernel,
or I can SET the default next boot kernel with grub2-reboot .
How, precisely can I do this if BLSCFG is in use ?
ie. I am looking for some 'grub2-show-menu-entries' shell script / command ,
that displays menu entry index #s I can pass to grub2-reboot ...

I ran into a similar problem when I added an LTS repo to a Fedora 41 VM. Getting a list of the current boot order is done with grubby:
sudo grubby --info=ALL | awk -F '(=)' '/title/ {print $2}' | tr -d \"
Fedora Linux (6.11.8-300.fc41.x86_64) 41 (Forty One)
Fedora Linux (6.6.62-200.fc41.x86_64) 41 (Forty One)

This list is shown in index order (starting with 0), so grub-reboot 1 would boot the 2nd entry listed. To get more information about your current boot entries, run this:
sudo grubby --info=ALL
index=0
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.11.8-300.fc41.x86_64"
args="ro selinux=0"
root="UUID=9056e92f-a773-49f6-9470-7cf4ae80b0a8"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.11.8-300.fc41.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.11.8-300.fc41.x86_64) 41 (Forty One)"
id="65b28911db9a4f70b577ca032cc03608-6.11.8-300.fc41.x86_64"
index=1
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-6.6.62-200.fc41.x86_64"
args="ro selinux=0"
root="UUID=9056e92f-a773-49f6-9470-7cf4ae80b0a8"
initrd="/boot/initramfs-6.6.62-200.fc41.x86_64.img"
title="Fedora Linux (6.6.62-200.fc41.x86_64) 41 (Forty One)"
id="65b28911db9a4f70b577ca032cc03608-6.6.62-200.fc41.x86_64"

I'm not sure how Fedora is setting the index order; only thing that's consistent is that the last installed kernel gets moved to index 0. The boot entries for BLSCFG Grub are located in /boot/loader/entries/.
